# How to remove everything from parens except if it contains given keywords

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I have this piece of code to filter out words from an incoming string:

```
RemoveWords = "\\b(official|videoclip|clip|video|mix|ft|feat|music|HQ|version|HD|original|extended|unextended|vs|preview|meets|anthem|12\"|4k|audio|rmx|lyrics|lyric|international|1080p)\\b"
result = re.compile(RemoveWords, re.I)
```

This was kind of a workaround because I just started with Python.
Now what would be ideal is the following:

> If the parens contain the words 'remix' or 'edit': don't remove text
>   within parens. Otherwise remove everything from the parens including
>   the parens itself.

For example, if a title looks like this:

> AC/DC - T.N.T. (from Live at River Plate)

Everything between the parens has to be removed.

But if a title looks like this:

> AC/DC - T.N.T. (Dj Example Remix)

Don't remove text between parens, because it contains the word remix.

I know how to remove words that match the regex, but I don't know how to keep it between parens or how to delete everything between that if it doesn't contain the given words.

I've tried looking up on regex to find out how to limit it between parens, but I couldn't figure it out as I'm also new to Regex in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `re.finditer()` and `re.search()` functions:

```
import re
titles = 'AC/DC - T.N.T. (from Live at River Plate) AC/DC - T.N.T. (Dj Example Remix)'
result = titles

for m in re.finditer(r'\([^()]+\)', titles):
    if not re.search(r'\b(remix|edit)\b', m.group(), re.I):
        result = re.sub(re.escape(m.group()), '', result)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
AC/DC - T.N.T.  AC/DC - T.N.T. (Dj Example Remix)
```

Comment: Which method would be faster? @Ajax1234's answer throws an error when there are no parentheses in the string, this is also possible. So how I handle that

Comment: @KeesSonnema, my approach can cover an input string with multiple groups of parenthesis (as you see) and it won't throw any error if there is no paranthesis

Comment: That's very convenient. Because there are cases that it has two sets of parentheses. Would it also just pass strings without parentheses?

Comment: Oh just figured that out. You first search for parentheses before searching. nvm my lack of brain :) +1

Comment: @KeesSonnema, yes, the 1st step - searching parentheses, the 2nd step - analyzing content within found parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re


keep_words = ["remix", "edit"]

s = "AC/DC - T.N.T. (Dj Example Remix)"

words = [i.lower() for i in s[s.index("(")+1:s.index(")")].split()]

new_s = re.sub("\((.*?)\)", "", s) if  not any(i in keep_words for i in words) else s
```

Output:

```
AC/DC - T.N.T. (Dj Example Remix)
```

In this case, the code will retain the parenthesis, because a word between them appears in `stop_words`. However, if `s = "AC/DC - T.N.T. (from Live at River Plate)"`, the Output will be:

```
AC/DC - T.N.T.
```

Explanation:

For this solution, the algorithm finds the content between the parenthesis and splits it. Then, the code converts all the values to lowercase that exist in that new list. The regular expression works like this:

```
"\(" => escape character: finding the first parenthesis in the string
"(.*?)" => matches all the content between specific strings, in this case the outside parenthesis: \( and \)
"\)" => last parenthesis. It must be escaped by the backslash so that it will not be confused for the command to search between specific tags
```

If a match is found and any item from `keep_words` is not found in between the parenthesis, the regular expression will remove all data between the parenthesis and substitute it with a empty string: `""`

Comment: The idea is to get rid of the stop_words and use `remix/edit/what else I come up with` as keep_words. My string can be every song title you could imagine, so. just fyi

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed, couldn't figure it out. Could you add an explanation per part? That would be great :)

Comment: @KeesSonnema glad to help! Please see my recent edit for the explanation.

Comment: If there are no parentheses in the string it fails, how would I handle that?

Comment: @KeesSonnema you would have to structure the code a little differently. If there are no parenthesis, then how would you determine what band is playing and what part of the string contains the description of the performance? In my view, you would need a list of bands or a list of possible words that would comprise the description of the performance. From there, it is a very easy problem as all you would need to do is filter the original input.

Comment: I don't need a list of performances. All I need is an artist and a title, which I get now. @RomanPerekhrest's answer looks more fail proof to me. Only question is if it would be faster.